# How to stop Generic Url from encoding url

Tags: rest, oauth, google-oauth, jira

I have been using `google.api.client.http.GenericUrl` for fetching issues from Jira.

For extracting issues from Jira it uses `jql` url parameter, e.g.: https://ip_address/jira/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=KAFKA.

The output of this will be a list of issues for project key 'KAFKA' in `json`. 
GenericUrl is encoding `=` to `%3D`.

In this case, the current url becomes https://ip_address/jira/rest/api/latest/search?jql%3Dproject=KAFKA
which is extracting all issues of all projects and not for a specified key. 
Ideally its output should be limited to the given key.

Following is my code:

```
String jiraUrl="https://ip_address/jira/rest/api/latest/search?";
GenericUrl geneUrl = new GenericUrl(jiraUrl);       
geneUrl.set("jql=project", projectKey);
geneUrl.set("maxResults", batchSize);
geneUrl.set("startAt", page);
HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(geneUrl);
```

I tried following

```
GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl=("https://ip_address/jira/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=KAFKA&maxResults=100&startA=0);
```

but it is changing the url to
 `https://ip_address/jira/rest/api/latest/search**jql=projectKAFKA**&maxResults=100&startA=0` 
which is failing.

How do I fix this? Is it possible to pass the url as is without encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed. I did following

```
GenericUrl geneUrl = new GenericUrl(jiraUrl);       
geneUrl.set("jql", "project="+projectKey);
geneUrl.set("maxResults", batchSize);
geneUrl.set("startAt", page);
```